# VB.NET Download File Fails

Tags: vb.net

I'm downloading a file through my software and it completes the first time. But the second time it fails if I save it to the same directory. It overwrites the file, but refuses to download. If I save it to another directory it completes, but then I have to save it to yet another directory, or I can use the same directory as the original with success.
I would like to save this file in the same directory every time with the same name, otherwise my program won't locate this file if needed to be run.
any help please

My Code:

```
Private Sub Updt_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Updt.Click

    Dim VlcGetUrl64 As String = " http://update.videolan.org/vlc/status-win-x64" 'Gets new update url
    Dim Vlc64Dir As String = "Software\x64\vlc.exe" 'Save file as
    Dim VlcSaveUrl As String = "Software\x64\updateUrl.txt" 'Save file url

    Try
        Using client = New WebClient()
            Using stream = client.OpenRead("http://www.google.com")

                If System.Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem = True Then

                    Try
                        ' Make a WebClient.
                        Dim web_client As WebClient = New WebClient

                        ' Download the file.
                        web_client.DownloadFile(VlcGetUrl, VlcSaveUrl)
                        Dim Counter As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(VlcSaveUrl)(1) 'Read URL in updateUrl.txt
                        web_client.DownloadFile(Counter, Vlc64Dir) 
                        Form2.RichTextBox1.AppendText(ChrW(&H2713))

                    Catch ex As Exception
                        TextBox1.Text = "Done"
                    End Try
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        TextBox1.Text = "Error"

    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: If you can download the file to the same location the file already exists in only after a period of time passes, then something is holding that file open initially so it can’t be overwritten.

Comment: So do you think I should first add a file delete before downloading?